# Naturality of ribbon category twists

Tags: ct.category-theory, knot-theory, braided-tensor-categories

[*Tortile Tensor Categories*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82259745.pdf) by Shum defines a twist to be a natural transformation $\theta : \operatorname{Id} \to \operatorname{Id}$ satisfying some axioms. However, wikipedia and nLab worded the definition implying that the naturality is not needed. Quote wikipedia:

> ... has a family of twists. [...] The twists are maps $C \in \mathcal C, \theta_C : C \to C$ such that ...

And quote nLab:

> A **twist** on rigid braided monoidal category is a set of isomorphisms $\theta_X : X \to X$ for which ...

So is the naturality condition not needed, deducible from the other axioms (perhaps only in the specific case of ribbon categories, and not general braided categories equipped with twists)? I think I have constructed a counterexample using finite dimensional vector spaces, but I'm not sure if I missed some axioms to check.

Comment: I would have assumed that naturality is needed, or at least some kind of coherence. Be aware that the nLab is not an encyclopaedia, and can and should need editing to be corrected at times. Pages there are like notes when learning stuff, editable by everyone.

Comment: I notice you've fixed the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ribbon+category) to include naturality, thanks!